# Broken symlinks in /etc/systemd

Tags: debian, systemd

There are a few broken symlinks in **/etc/systemd/{system,user}** like this one:

```
anacron.timer -> /lib/systemd/system/anacron.timer
```

but there is no anacron.timer in **/lib/systemd/system**. Instead there is anacron.timer in **/usr/lib/systemd/system** (maybe because of some kind of migration, I don't know) and timer and service works correctly.

Is it a good (systemd 247.9) practice to manually remove this broken symlinks from **/etc/systemd** ? or should it be done by package maintainer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sort of problem is supposed to be fixed by the package maintainer. In `anacron`’s case, the bug is filed as [#993348](https://bugs.debian.org/993348): the previous version of `anacron` shipped its systemd files in `/lib/systemd`, the new version moved them to `/usr/lib/systemd` but didn’t update any symlinks in `/etc`.

However `/etc` is owned by the system administrator, not the package manager, so it’s fine for you to clean up the mess too. The links aren’t necessary, you might as well delete them.

Comment: Thank you. I assume that other broken symlinks in `/etc/systemd` are in similar situation.

Comment: Yes, that’s quite likely. If you don’t mind, it would be great if you could check whether corresponding bugs are filed, and report them if necessary!

Answer (score 1):

The package is broken for some reasons, you should have `anacron.timer` under `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`, [here is the list of files](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/amd64/anacron/filelist) provided by `anacron`.

The symlinked `anacron.timer` can be:

```
ls -al /etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/anacron.timer

 /etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/anacron.timer -> /lib/systemd/system/anacron.timer
```

Reinstall `anacron`:

```
sudo apt purge anacorn
sudo apt install anacron
```